# Semantic-ui-react style not loaded

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am trying to learn react with semantic ui but I have a problem with the style from semantic ui. Then I try follow the docs from https://react.semantic-ui.com/
but the style is not loaded

Here's my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Table, Icon, Menu, Label } from 'semantic-ui-react';

class App extends Component {

  // Here's my other code

  render() {
    const data = this.state.data
      if (this.state.error) {
        return (<p>Error : {this.state.error.message}</p>);
      } else if (!this.state.isloaded) {
        return (<p>Loading ...</p>);
      } else {
        return (
          <Table celled>
            <Table.Header>
              <Table.Row>
                <Table.HeaderCell>Network</Table.HeaderCell>
                <Table.HeaderCell>Address</Table.HeaderCell>
                <Table.HeaderCell>Balance</Table.HeaderCell>
              </Table.Row>
            </Table.Header>

            <Table.Body>
              <Table.Row>
                <Table.Cell>
                  <Label ribbon>{data.network}</Label>
                </Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell>{data.address}</Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell>{data.confirmed}</Table.Cell>
              </Table.Row>
            </Table.Body>

            <Table.Footer>
              <Table.Row>
                <Table.HeaderCell colSpan='3'>
                  <Menu floated='right' pagination>
                  <Menu.Item as='a' icon>
                    <Icon name='chevron left' />
                  </Menu.Item>
                  <Menu.Item as='a'>1</Menu.Item>
                  <Menu.Item as='a'>2</Menu.Item>
                  <Menu.Item as='a'>3</Menu.Item>
                  <Menu.Item as='a'>4</Menu.Item>
                  <Menu.Item as='a' icon>
                    <Icon name='chevron right' />
                  </Menu.Item>
                </Menu>
              </Table.HeaderCell>
            </Table.Row>
          </Table.Footer>
        </Table>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the result
[image: Only text not with style]

I am not using webpack

Comment: That's tough! A page without styles is discouraging. However, please read [ask]. As it stands, this question does not provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Rafael, i disagree with your judgement here. People familiar with Semantic don't need that example. it's much harder to spin up an environment like that and really not necessary.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Seems like a package possibly was not installed. Try these steps below:

### Adding the packages with NPM

1a. `npm install semantic-ui-react`

2a. `npm install semantic-ui-css`

### Adding the packages with Yarn

1b. `yarn add semantic-ui-react`

2b. `yarn add semantic-ui-css`

### Project setup

In your **index.js** file add

```
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'
```

### Running your project

Now you should be ready! Run your app and you should see the styles, you may have to clear cache in some cases.

---

#### Further Reading

https://react.semantic-ui.com/usage/

Comment: Thank you. i will try it 

Answer (score 0):

If you installed the `semantic-ui-css` package and continue to has this problem, maybe you forgot to import it in the `index.js` file of your react project.

```js
//index.js
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, 'Get Started' in [semantic-ui-react docs](https://react.semantic-ui.com/usage) not working.

So I found workaround. (I'm using [coreui-react-admin-pro](https://coreui.io/pro/react/))

## Solution

- My directory structure looks like below.
- Put `semantic.min.css` in the `public` directory.

```
my-app/
├─ node_modules/
├─ public/
│  ├─ index.html
│  ├─ semantic.min.css
│  ├─ robots.txt
├─ src/
│  ├─ App.js
│  ├─ index.js
├─ .gitignore
├─ package.json
├─ README.md
```

- And edit `public/index.html`

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- ... -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/semantic.min.css" />
    <!-- ... -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Please note link in head tag</h1>
    <!-- ... -->
  </body>
 </html>
```